# Try catch statement has inconsistent return error, typescript

Tags: typescript, try-catch

I have a typescript function that is giving me an error about inconsistent return. I know that I return in the try and throw an error in the catch, so technically nothing is returned in the catch statement. However, I'm not sure how to work around it.

```
async function someFunction(): Promise<Course> {
    try {
        // some code logic to create a Course object
        return courseObject;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new ApolloError(....);
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve] - it looks like you are trying to make an async function without `async`

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't an `async` function but it is expected to return a Promise. Therefore, you need to wrap the return value and error as a Promises:

```js
function someFunction(): Promise<Course> {
    try {
        // some code logic to create a Course object
        return Promise.resolve(courseObject);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(new ApolloError(...));
    }
}
```

Or turn your function `async`:

```js
async function someFunction(): Promise<Course> {
    try {
        // some code logic to create a Course object
        return courseObject;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new ApolloError(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put async in my simple code, it is an async function

Comment: In that case your code looks fine? Can't reproduce the error you're talking about. What TypeScript version are you using? Did you omit parts of your example code that also got rid of the error?

Comment: The parts I omitted are just http calls to get data so I can create the fields that make the Course object. I'm using Sonar to find these errors